# ProgressBar not updating in android

Tags: android, listview, android-progressbar

Hi i am new for android and in my app i have one listview when i tapped on listview item i need to go Details page and download files with update ProgressBar and so for Everything ok

Problem is when i go back My listview and come again to already downlodable file progress is value is updating but progressBar not updating can some one help me please

### code:-

```
@Override
    public void updateProgress(final float progress, final int downloadingState) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Downloading... " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (progress > 0 && progress < 100) {
                    progress_bar_download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    progress_bar_download.setProgress((int) progress);
                }  else {
                    progress_bar_download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: you have to increase the progress and sleep the thread to see the gradual increase too

Comment: can u explain with some code?

Comment: just a moment and I'll write it

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {                            
                while(progresso<100)
                {
                    progresso++;
                    handler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progresso);            
                        }
                    });
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }).start();
```

And add this line in the layout under the ProgressBar

```
android:max="100"
```